# Python: sort of scientific notation

Tags: floating-point, python-3.5, number-formatting, scientific-notation

I have a series of floating point numbers that I need to print out in a specific format, very similar to scientific notation.
Given the number -345.678, scientific notation would give me -3.45678E2 but instead I need to output -.345678D03. Specifically, I cannot have any digits to the left of the decimal point.  Is there any way to do this in Python 3?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the full details of your format, but the following should either work or be easily modifiable to work:

```
from decimal import Decimal

def sci_str(dec):
    return ('{:.' + str(len(dec.normalize().as_tuple().digits) - 1) + 'E}').format(dec)

def mod_sci_str(x):
    s = sci_str(10*Decimal(str(x)))
    s = s.replace('E+','D0')
    s = s.replace('E-','D0-')
    s = s.replace('.','')
    if s.startswith('-'):
        return '-.' + s[1:]
    else:
        return '.' + s
```

The function `sci_str` is a clever utility due to @MikeM in this question

For example:

```
>>> mod_sci_str(-345.678)
'-.345678D03'
>>> mod_sci_str(345.678)
'.345678D03' 
>>> mod_sci_str(0.0034)
'.34D0-2'
```